# Extreme points of a function.

Tags: functions

How do I find the extreme points of the following function?

> $$\begin{align}
> f(x)&\,=\,-\ln(x^2+x+1),\;-1\le x\le 0\\
> \\
> &\,=\,\sqrt{(x\lvert x^2-4\rvert)},\;x\gt 0\\
> \end{align}$$

I know I have to find the derivative, I found it for the first one but I'm having trouble deriving the second because of the absolute value.

Comment: Try splitting the absolute value into a piecewise function. Then you can take the derivative of each part on it's own.

Comment: consider the cases $0 <x <2$ and $x>2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first function.

$$f(x)=-\ln \left((x+\frac12)^2  +\frac34\right)$$

The function is symmetrical about $x=-\frac12.$

$(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34$ is a convex function with minimal point at $x=\frac12$. Notice that $-\ln(.)$ is a decreasing function.

Hence, the global minimum are at the boundary $-1$ and $0$ while the global maximum is at $x=-\frac12$.

For the second function.

$f(x) \geq 0$. hence the global minimum is attained when $x^2-4=0$, that is $x=2$.

Also, $\sqrt{.}$ is an increasing function. It suffices to study $$x|x^2-4|.$$

If $x > 2,$ the function become $$x(x^2-4)$$

If $x < 2$, the function become $$x(4-x^2)$$.

Now that we have get rid of the absolute value, are you able to solve the problem?

Remark: As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$.